# How to synchronize with a custom list on SharePoint

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-discovery

How can I keep Watson Discovery’s collection   synchronized with a custom list on SharePoint using the data crawler?
Is there a simple way to automatically update Watson’s data every time new data is added to SharePoint?